# Filling space left by uneven sized floated elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a menu which is a series of floated `li` in a `ul`. They are constrained by an outer container to fit in a maximum 700px width. The `li` are of variable width since they resize based on their content. Each of the `li` also has a background-color to make the effect look like a bar and border right and bottom to separate them from other items.

The floating and wrapping is working fine. What I want to do though is to fill in the "gap" at the end of the row where the next item didn't fit and so it wrapped. I want it to basically fill in an empty box (so same background-color and same borders separating it) to make it stretch to the 700px width it is constrained to.

I toyed with a background image. However I have a problem that in IE the elements floated to the next row are one pixel higher so a background image that consists of the box color and the bottom border doesn't work properly when it stretches to multi-rows.

Using a solid background-color means that when it is on a second row the filled in space doesn't have the separating row between the first and second rows.

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate the situations and allow you to toy with it: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/yR9dJ/ . Essentially in that demo I need the entirety of the red dashed box to be filled with the blueish background color with separating lines maintained.

I have full control of changing the HTML though would like to avoid going back to a table design but am happy to make any other changes as appropriate.

Stretching items to fill the space perfectly on the first row is acceptable though in the case where one item falls to the second row I don't think it would look good stretched to full width.

I'd rather avoid javascript solutions though if that is the only option I'll certainly consider them.

To make it clearer the end result I would like is basically this:

[image: This is how I want it to look]

This is when I tried doing it with background images and demonstrates the problem mentioned above with the second row being 1px taller than the first. Since FF has them both the same size this doesn't work so well in that.

Comment: Have you tried using ie only styles so you use a different background image in ie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some experiments and I came to this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jJwTL/

I tested on Fx10, IE8 and Chrome both with 1 or more lines. I used `display: inline-block` instead of float and it seems to work well

CSS

```
ul { 
  width          : 700px; 
  background     : #5ca7be; 
  overflow       : hidden;
  border         : 2px solid #848484; 
}
ul:after { display: block; margin-top: -3px; content: ""; }

li { 
  display     : inline-block; 
  position    : relative; 
  height      : 2em; line-height: 2em; 
  padding     : 0 12px;
  margin-top  : -2px;  
  color: #fff; border-right: 2px #fff solid; 
}


li:first-child { margin-bottom: 2px; }

li:before  {
    content   : ""; 
    position  : absolute; 
    left      : 0;
    top       : 0;
    display   : block; 
    width     : 700px; 
    height    : 2px; 
    background: #fff;
}
```

Since I used psuedolements this example won't work on IE<8. Hope this helps anyway

Comment: That looks perfect from that fiddle. It looks shocking when I set my browser to render as IE7 though (they are just stacked vertically). Sadly I'm not 100% sure what IE I might have to support but you have given me an excellent starting point. I'm going to wait a little while to see if anybody comes up with anything better before accepting though.

Comment: You can always apply a totally different 'make-do' set of styles for IE<8 so it doesn't display quite as badly. May be use the background image approach for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is updated CSS

```
.Menu {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
    `background-color:blue;`
    padding:10px;
}

.HorizontalMenu .MenuItem {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.15em 1.5em;
  color: white;
    `border:solid 2px blue;`
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I have just modifed these two classes. Gave Border Color for Horizantal Menu

Comment: This loses all the separating lines between the items sadly. In case you didn't see my edit I've included an image of what I'm after here if that helps clarify things for you.